# How to keep the first occurence of a value which is repeated in a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The df looks like below:

```
A   B   C
1   8   23
2   8   22
3   8   45
4   9   45
5   6   12
6   11  10
7   11  12
```

I want to drop the repeated occurence of '8'. I know there is a way for removing all the repeated occurence. But how to specify a certain value?

Expected output:

```
A   B   C
1   8   23
4   9   45
5   6   12
6   11  10
7   11  12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to identify duplicates with an `&` condition with the desired value to be removed and use `~` to turn False values to True and vice versa:

```
df[~(df['B'].duplicated() & df['B'].eq(8))]
```

---

```
   A   B   C
0  1   8  23
3  4   9  45
4  5   6  12
5  6  11  10
6  7  11  12
```